# how to change label tag on input box change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

say i have an input box and a label so when i type something on the input box, the label automatically changes as I typed.

example:

```
//the result 4 is dynamically put in the label as a result of input value.
<label class="result">4</label>

//this is the input where i put a value of 2
<input type="text" class="amount" name="amount" value="2" onkeyup="compute()">

//this is the function that is called to perform the calc.
 function compute()
{
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("amount");
    document.getElementsByClassName("result").value = x.value + 2;

}
```

in the example above, I put 2 and the result is immediately outputted in the label as a result of the calculation.

Comment: If you don't show some jQuery code that you've tried, this question will most certainly get closed.

Comment: Please add your javascript code.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? You want to set the text of the `input` to `4` by clicking on the `label`? Is this the *only* thing you want to do, or does it vary in some way with other buttons? And what's the `result = 2 + 2;` got to do with anything?

Comment: @DavidThomas its just an example. what i want to do is when i typed 2 in the input box, the result will be 4 as a result of a function adding 2 + 2 and displayed in the label.

Comment: _Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved._

Comment: @Jeffman i was just editing my code when a -2 was given.

Comment: @Thew I have added the code but it seems not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### JavaScript

use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("result").innerHTML = x.value + 2;
```

Instead of

```
document.getElementsByClassName("result").value = x.value + 2;
```

Because, label will not have any value! :) You are trying to update the value, which ain't gonna happen!

## jQuery

If you want to use jQuery for this then use

```
var x = $('.amount').val();
$('.result').html(x + 2);
```

Then wrap them inside the `function`.

I hope it works! :)

Comment: Try using jQuery! :) And I guess, you might want to read the console log :) Press F12 :) You will see errors or warnings at the left bottom..you can read them :) They will help you alot..

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, not one element like `getElementById`.